# Wrong code in tutorial for event listeners

Tags: listener, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/building-a-store-locator/) to build a store locator page with a Mapbox map.

I don't want to add custom markers because I already have custom map labels (symbols?), which means I don't need the optional last section of the tutorial and stop right after [Add Event Listeners](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/building-a-store-locator/#add-event-listeners).

Once this is completed, the page should react to clicks in the side panel list, as well as on the map (2 event listeners). However, in the [demo provided in the tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/demos/gl-store-locator/step-four.html) for that particular step, you can tell the code for the second event listener, the one making the map clickable, is not functioning, which makes me believe there is a mistake in the provided code:

```
// Add an event listener for when a user clicks on the map
map.on('click', function(e) {
  // Query all the rendered points in the view
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['locations'] });
  if (features.length) {
    var clickedPoint = features[0];
    // 1. Fly to the point
    flyToStore(clickedPoint);
    // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
    createPopUp(clickedPoint);
    // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
    var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    if (activeItem[0]) {
      activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
    }
    // Find the index of the store.features that corresponds to the clickedPoint that fired the event listener
    var selectedFeature = clickedPoint.properties.address;

    for (var i = 0; i < stores.features.length; i++) {
      if (stores.features[i].properties.address === selectedFeature) {
        selectedFeatureIndex = i;
      }
    }
    // Select the correct list item using the found index and add the active class
    var listing = document.getElementById('listing-' + selectedFeatureIndex);
    listing.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

Would anyone be able to tell what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Anyone uses Mapbox out here?

Comment: I don't actually get why you says it's not working. You may customize some part of the code so there's some mismatched code?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is incomplete in that the cursor doesn't change to a pointer as you hover over a map label/marker so it doesn't clue you into realising you can click on it, hence my assumption it wasn't working at all. I assume the general users who would then face the map would be equally deceived unless the pointer shows up. So in the tutorial, if you do go ahead and click the marker, it will have the expected behaviour and display the popup, although no pointer is shown.

Here is how to create the pointer, based on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twalsh88/5j70wm8n/25/

```
map.on('mouseenter', 'locations', function(e) {
   // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
   map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

 });
 map.on('mouseleave', 'locations', function() {
   map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
 });
```